# How to record video directly on the server without asking user to upload

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, video-processing, video-recording

Instead of asking user to upload a video file - I want the user to directly record online and save it. Like with his webcam on - he visits the website, clicks on the record button - records his message and clicks done - the video is saved on my server.

Something like what is described for youtube here:
http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57409

How difficult or easy is it to do this. Any tips, examples, ideas
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.red5-recorder.com/demo.php

Does just this.

Answer (score 2):

YouTube uses a Flash applet to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a Java applet that would record the video on client-side and once the whole video is recorded post it on your script url as a normal file, you would then process it as a normal file upload. I used a similar technique for recording audio using Java Sound API. You can google and you will find an opensource applet.

Comment: Thanks ovais - do you know of any open source applet that lets you record video

Comment: i will search for it and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in straight html.

You can use any client side technology that allows you to get access to the camera and record from it.  This includes a java applet, flash, or silverlight.